# Create a script that kills the process at a specific port

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a shell script, as portable as possible ("POSIX"), which kills the process at a specific port. I know I can use this:

`portpid() { fstat | grep ":$1" | awk '{print $3}' ;}`

Then, we can kill a process listening on port 8080, like this:

`$ kill $(portpid 8080)`

But how can I put it together as a program that kills the process at the port in a oneliner and add this script as a named alias to my commands and path?

I suppose it should look something like the following.

```
portpid() { fstat | grep ":$1" | awk '{print $3}' ;}

kill $(portpid $1)
```

I try to put it together but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
portpid() { fstat | grep ":$1" | awk '{print $3}' ;}    
kill $(portpid $1)
```

I am using Korn shell. This is my first shell script.

Comment: I suppose, `fstat` can not be just called as is from command line. What's your OS and what's your current `fstat` output?

Comment: If you don't _tell people your operating system_, then people telling you to use `lsof` on a BSD is the sort of thing that results.  Is this MacOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it is nor working" is often heard/read but hardly usefull.

You use a shebang for bash (#!/bin/bash ) as use korn shell, do at least /bin/bash exist on your system ? For this small script you may use /bin/ksh as well.

What you did will expand to (called with 80)

```
#!/bin/bash
portpid() { fstat | grep ":80" | awk '{print $3}' ;}    
kill $(portpid 80)
```

This is not what you want.

To feed the result of `fstat` to `kill` use

```
portpid() { fstat | grep ":$1" | awk '{print $3;}' | xargs kill }
```

Where xargs will read input from previous command and call kill.

Awk can do greping, rather use

```
portpid() { fstat |  awk '/'$1'/ {print $3;}' | xargs kill }
```

You seems to know about awk syntax, if port number is at a specific field (let's say 7), use

```
portpid() { fstat |  awk '$7 ~ /'$1'/ {print $3;}' | xargs kill }
```

Comment: Just contracting it to `awk '/:'$1'/ { print $3;}'` can be done without reference to the output format.  (-:  As mentioned in comments on the answer that uses `lsof` instead of `fstat`, the question strongly implies OpenBSD `fstat`, given that FreeBSD `fstat` does not have the port numbers in its output to match in this way.

Comment: If you want to write an _even better_ answer, you'll note that the reason that the shell script does not work on OpenBSD with the Korn shell is in its very first line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lsof with xargs and kill for this

```
killport() { lsof -i ":$1" -t | xargs kill }
```

or

```
 killport() { kill $(lsof -i ":$1" -t)  }
```

lsof specifically contains a flag for just this

> **-t**
>   This option specifies that lsof should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output may be piped to kill(1). This option selects the -w option.

Comment: The questioner _does not have_ `lsof` (unless this is one particular case).  The questioner is using `fstat`, as in the question, which is the equivalent of `lsof` on the questioner's operating system.

Comment: @JdeBP How could you possibly know that? Also the question is `Create a script that kills the process at a specific port` with no mention of a specific command, nor does it anywhere in the question specify the OS or available programs.

Comment: The `fstat` command is right there in the question, three times, and you can see its output being `grep`ed for a port number, strongly implying OpenBSD `fstat` specifically (since FreeBSD `fstat` does not print port numbers and IP addresses).  There is no `lsof` on OpenBSD or FreeBSD.  `fstat` is the equivalent command.

Comment: @JdeBP https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html lol

Comment: That's from Ports.  That does not come in the operating system.  Correct the selection that you have made at the top to not include "and Ports" and you can see this.  Or just try running the command on a vanilla FreeBSD or OpenBSD system and witness that there's no such command.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Where does it say they're running vanilla BSD, you're acting as though all your assumptions are fact...